# How do i create a 3d array using a int array with a length of 3 to define the size of said 3d array?

Tags: java, arrays

how do i do:
`char[][][] map = new char[y][z][x];`
but define the size with:

> int[] size = new {y,z,x};

I tried looking it up but i couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Your title says int array but your example uses a char array.  And what are all the dimensions for x,y,and z?

Comment: `int x = size[2]; int y = size[0]; int z = size[1]; char[][][] map = new char[y][z][x];`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking to initialize the array with a set of values.
As opposed to initializing an array with a fixed length, and then adding the values one at a time.

Your code is correct, just remove the `new` keyword.

```java
int[] size = { y, z, x };
```